# Find the solution to the first order ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution to

$x′= y−x+t $
and
$y'= y $

if $x(0)=8$ and $y(0)=2$

I'm confused how to go about this question. If anyone could offer some clarification that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is described for example here: http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-LinearSystems.pdf

Comment: Thank you all so much! These are the steps I took: $$ dy/dt = y$$ $$1/y = dt$$ Then taking the integral, $$ ln(y) = t + C$$ $$ C = ln 2$$ $$ y(t) = 2e^{t}$$ And then for the x, $$x' = 2e^{t} - x + t$$ $$dx/dt + x = 2e^{t} + t$$

Comment: Oops I couldn't edit that comment anymore, but I got the final answer of $$x(t) = e^{t} +t - 1 + 8e^{-t}$$ Thanks for the guidance guys!

Comment: @LeahL Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

First solve the second equation as it does not contain $x$. Then insert
$$
y(t)=2e^t
$$
into the first equation and solve via your preferred method, integrating factor, homogeneous plus particular solution etc.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

The system is in the form

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x^\prime \\y^\prime
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1\\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\y
\end{bmatrix}
+t\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\0
\end{bmatrix} \quad \vec x^{\prime}=A \vec x+t\vec b$$

Firstly we need to find the complementary solution to $\vec x^{\prime}=A \vec x$ assuming $\vec x=\vec u\cdot e^{at}$ that is

$$a\cdot \vec u\cdot e^{at}=A\vec u\cdot e^{at}\implies(A-aI)\vec u=0$$

and from here we can find the eigenvalues, the eigenvectors and the complementary solution $\vec x_c$ to the system.

Then we need to find the particular solution to $\vec x^{\prime}=A \vec x+t\vec b$ assuming

$$\vec x_p=t\vec v + \vec w \implies \vec x_p^{\prime}=\vec v$$

and then

$$\vec v=tA\vec v+A\vec w+t\vec b\implies t(A\vec v+\vec b)+(A\vec w-\vec u)=0 $$

that is

- $A\vec v+\vec b=\vec 0$ from which we find $\vec v$
- $A\vec w-\vec v=\vec 0$ from which we find $\vec w$

Then the general solution is $\vec x=\vec x_c+\vec x_p$ and we can impose the initial condition to find the constants in $\vec x_c$.

[**Here**](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SolutionsToSystems.aspx) you can find some worked example.

Answer (score 0):

First solve the second equation 
$$y'=y \implies \ln |y|=t+K_1 \implies y=K_1e^t$$
Then solve first equation
$$x′= y−x+t$$
$$x'+x=K_1e^t+t$$
Multiply by $e^t$
$$(xe^t)'=K_1e^{2t}+te^t$$
Integrate
$$xe^t= \int K_1e^{2t}+te^t dt $$
$$......$$